# How do I resolve this design constraint in mongo db w.r.t to performance?

Tags: mongodb

Currently I have something as below.

Collection1 - system

```
{
  _id: system_id,
  ... system fields
  system_name: ,
  system_site: ,
  system_group: ,
  ....
  device_errors: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}
```

I have 2K unique error codes.

I have an error collection as below.

```
{
 _id: error_id,
 category,
 impact,
 action,
}
```

I have got a use case where each each `system|burt` combination can have unique `error_description` because error has some system data.

I am confused how to handle this in this scenario.

```
 One system can have many errors. 
 One error can be part of multiple systems.
```

Now, how to maintain the unique details of a burt specific to a system? I thought of having a nested field instead array in system collection. I am wondering about the scalability.

Any suggestion?

```
 system1|burt1
    error_desc:unique system1

 system2|burt1
    error_Description: unique
```

If I store like above in another collection, API request has to make three calls and form the response.

```
 1. Find all errors for set of systems
 2. Find top 50 burts from point1
 3. For top 50 burts, find error desc
```

Combine all three call responses and reply to the user?

I am not thinking it is best as we need to make 3 data source calls to respond a request.

I have already tried flatten structure with redundant data.

```
{   
 ... system1_info
 ... error1_info
},
{
 ... system2_info  
 ... error1_info
},
{  
 ... system1_info
 ... error2_info
},
{
 ... system10_info  
 ... error1200_info
}
```

Here, I am using many aggregation as below in single query

```
1. Match
2. Group error
3. Sort
4. total count of errors - another group
5. Project
```

I feel it is a heavier query than the `approach1[actual question]`.

Let's say I have `2k errors, 20million systems = I have totally 40million doc`. 
**In worst case** each system has 2k errors. My query should support more than 1 system. Let's say I have to query for 25k systems.

1. 25k systems * 2k errors => match result
2. Apply all the mentioned above operations
3. Then slice to 100[For pagination]

If I go with relational model like without redundancy, I will get 25k systems, then i have to query for only 2k errors = It is very less operation than above aggregation.

Comment: It is not opinion based. It has to do with database features and simplification w.r.t query execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the set of possible errors does not change very frequently. Cache it in the application.