# Mongo DB - array of object with unique fields along with other collection references

Tags: mongodb

```
{
 _id: device1,
 issues:[
   {
    _id:issue125,
    desc: device1 port1 not reponding
   },
   {
    _id:issue766,
    desc: device1 software-X update needed
   },
 ]
},
{
 _id: device2,
 issues:[
   {
    _id:issue125,
    desc: device1 port2 not reponding
   },
   {
    _id:issue766,
    desc: device1 software-Y update needed
   },
 ]
}
```

I have a device collection and issue collection. Issue rules are unique. It has some device specific data such as port1, port2, softwareX, softwareY. issue125 says some ports not responding. issue766 says some software update needed. That is system specific.

I have a use case where I need to get all the devices owned by a user and find unique burts. I need to achieve something as

```
 {
   issue_id:125,
   ...CommonIssueInformationFromIssueCollection,
   devices:[
     {
       _id:device1,
       ...device1_Information_From_device_Collection,
       issue_desc: device1 port1 not reponding
     },
     {
       _id:device2,
       ...device1_Information_From_device_Collection,
       issue_desc: device1 port2 not reponding
     }
   ]
},
{
   issue_id:766,
   ...CommonIssueInformationFromIssueCollection,
   devices:[
     {
       _id:device1,
       ...device1_Information_From_device_Collection,
       issue_desc: software-X update needed
     },
     {
       _id:device2,
       ...device1_Information_From_device_Collection,
       issue_desc: software-Y update needed
     }
   ]
}
```

I can find the list of devices in a group[TATA group]. It will give me 20K devices. Each device can have max 2K entries in issues array. Issue ids are unique and only issue description differs per system.

I am not sure how to achieve the desired result in an optimal way. I have bits and pieces like `aggregate` with `unwind` I am not able to get it exactly as I need to avoid duplicate issue ids but not desc. I need unique issue ids to query `issue` collection.

Comment: Is that top bit you provided the documents from one of the collections, or are those already been combined?

Answer (score 1):

One possible aggregation:

- unwind issues
- add description to the root document
- group by issue _id and push each root document onto an array
- lookup the relevant data from the issues collection
- sort by the seriousness value
- remove the issues array nested in each device

Note that this might require "allowDiskUse" if the data size exceeds the limit.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$issues"},
  {$addFields: {desc: "$issues.desc"}},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$issues._id",
      devices: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {$lookup: {
        from: "issuesCollection",
        localField: "$_id",
        foreignField: "$_id",
        as: "issueData"
  }},
  {$sort: {"issueData.0.seriousness": -1}},
  {$limit: 50}
  {$project: {"devices.issues": 0 }}
])
```

If the issue seriousness doesn't change very often, add it in the issues array in the device document so you can do that sort without a lookup.

Comment: I have got [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JVigTvSCvWf). Here the main problem I face is that I will get 2000 issues for 1million systems. I need to show only top 50 issues based on the seriousness of the issue which is identified from issue collection

Comment: How is "top 50" determined?

Comment: Top 50 identified based on a field in other `issue` collection. Field value is integer. issue_priority is the field name. Based on this number, top 50 is decided.

Comment: I am worried on couple of things. I can get the issues for set of devices. Then for the issues received, I need to query issue collection. Get issue fields and top 50. The problem is that network-round-trip-time caused by first query[querying device collection]. Then I need to get device_issue specific description.

Comment: More details can be find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61272974/how-do-i-resolve-this-design-constraint-in-mongo-db-w-r-t-to-performance). I arrived to this design but I faces the access problem w.r.t the performance

Comment: Thanks Joe, I will try that.